# Different SO tab in different browser tabs

Tags: feature-request

I monitor several tags, with varying degrees of popularity, in a series of browser tabs. I would like to be able to choose the SO "Newest" tab for low activity tags, but a more selective SO tab such as "Featured" for a high activity tab.

Currently, when I select an SO tab in one browser tab, that selection is applied to all browser tabs the next time I refresh them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This already works.

URL for featured Java questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=featured

URL for newest Haskell questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell?sort=newest

Sometimes the `sort` parameter is not present; in those cases SO will go to the last selected tab. But make sure to click on the tab specifically, and the `sort` parameter is added, and it will work.